# Calculate wpm for each word

Tags: reactjs, datetime, math

I am trying to calculate the wpm for each word in a word-list based on the time taken to type each word, so that I can present the data in a graph like the result graph in [monkeytype.com](https://monkeytype.com/)

```
const Test = () => {
    const [startTime, setStartTime] = useState(0);
    const [wordWPMs, setWordWPMs]: any = useState([]);
    const [currentIndex, setCurrentIndex] = useState(0);
    const {
        time: { timer },
        word: { currWord, wordList, typedHistory, typedWord },
        preferences: { time },
    } = useSelector((state: State) => state);

    const dispatch = useDispatch();
    const extraLetters = typedWord.slice(currWord.length).split("");
    const activeWord = useRef<HTMLDivElement>(null);
    const caretRef = useRef<HTMLSpanElement>(null);
    const spaces = wordList.indexOf(currWord);
    let correctChars = 0;
    const result = typedHistory.map(
        (typedWord, idx) => typedWord === wordList[idx]
    );
    result.forEach((r, idx) => {
        if (r) correctChars += wordList[idx].length;
    });
    const wpm = ((correctChars + spaces) * 60) / time / 5;
    const correctWords = result.filter((x) => x).length;
    const incorrectWords = result.filter((x) => !x).length;
    const totalWords = correctWords + incorrectWords;
    const accuracy = (correctWords / totalWords) * 100 ? (correctWords / totalWords) * 100 : 0;

    useEffect(() => {
        dispatch(setRef(activeWord));
        dispatch(setCaretRef(caretRef));
    }, [dispatch]);

    useEffect(() => {
        if (typedWord === wordList[currentIndex]) {
          // start timing the word
          if (startTime === 0) {
            setStartTime(Date.now());
          }
        } else {
          // calculate WPM for the completed word
          if (startTime !== 0) {
            const elapsedTime = Date.now() - startTime;
            const wpm = (wordList[currentIndex].length * 60) / (elapsedTime / 1000) / 5; // issue here
            setWordWPMs([...wordWPMs, wpm]);
            setCurrentIndex(currentIndex + 1);
            setStartTime(0);
          }
        }
        console.log(wordWPMs)
      }, [typedWord, wordList, currentIndex, startTime, wordWPMs]);
      
    // record time taken to type each word and append it to an array
    // record no of wrong characters for each word and append it to an array

    return (
        <div style={{ display: "flex", width: "100", justifyContent: "center" }}>
            <div className="test">
                <div className="box">
                    {wordList.map((word, idx) => {
                        const isActive =
                            currWord === word && typedHistory.length === idx;
                        return (
                            <div
                                key={word + idx}
                                className="word"
                                ref={isActive ? activeWord : null}>
                                {isActive ? (
                                    <span
                                        ref={caretRef}
                                        id="caret"
                                        className="blink"
                                        style={{
                                            left: typedWord.length * 12.5833, // change based on letter
                                        }}>
                                        |
                                    </span>
                                ) : null}
                                {word.split("").map((char, charId) => {
                                    return <span key={char + charId}>{char}</span>;
                                })}
                                {isActive
                                    ? extraLetters.map((char, charId) => {
                                        return (
                                            <span
                                                key={char + charId}
                                                className="wrong extra">
                                                {char}
                                            </span>
                                        );
                                    })
                                    : typedHistory[idx]
                                        ? typedHistory[idx]
                                            .slice(wordList[idx].length)
                                            .split("")
                                            .map((char, charId) => {
                                                return (
                                                    <span
                                                        key={char + charId}
                                                        className="wrong extra">
                                                        {char}
                                                    </span>
                                                );
                                            })
                                        : null}
                            </div>
                        );
                    })}
                </div>
            </div>
        </div>
    );
}
```

If I typed 16 words in a 15 second test, here is the `wordWPMs` array:

```
[277.456647398844, 189.4736842105263, 335.6643356643357, 173.0769230769231, 480, 483.2214765100672, 480, 390.2439024390244, 259.4594594594595, 533.3333333333333, 384, 439.7905759162303, 155.03875968992247, 533.3333333333334, 390.2439024390244, 806.7226890756303]
```

According to my typing speed, the wpm in the array should have ranged from 100-120